# What is the population of Bas-Lag?

Tags: china-mieville, bas-lag

[China Miéville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_Mi%C3%A9ville)'s novels *Perdido Street Station*, *The Scar*, and *Iron Council* have all been set in the fictional world of [Bas-Lag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bas-Lag), which has a long history with numerous empires and societies and several intelligent species.

**Do we have any figures for the population of Bas-Lag?**

Ball-park figures will do; even an order of magnitude (to within a factor of 10) would be nice.

Comment: Huh, no way to tell for sure. And for some creatures it would be debatable if they should be counted. I'd guess somewhere between 100 millions and billion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about the population of Bas-Lag as a whole, but a hint at the size of New Crobuzon's population is given in *Perdido Street Station*.

Isaac guesses that the garuda population in Spatters is around 2000. He estimates that they make up around 0.03% of the city's total population.

With those numbers, we can assume the population is around 6,666,666.

> "Almost all the garuda in the city live in those four buildings. There probably aren't two thousand in the whole of New Crobuzon. That makes them about ... uh ... nought point fucking nought three per cent of the population ..." Isaac grinned. "I've been doing my research, see?"